# What does that mean: packages excluded due to repository priority protections

Tags: yum, update, mirror, centos6

When updating with yum i recieve the following message:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
118 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

What does that mean ? How to install these packages ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Some packages are held by more than one repository. The `priorities` plugin choose packages from the highest-priority repository, excluding duplicate entries from other repos.

Answer (score 79):

From what I understand, this error is generated from the `priorities` plugin as noted by Pawel.

In 2009, the [maintainer of yum mentioned](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) that he hoped people would not use `priorities`. To disable the priorities plugin, edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf` and set `enabled = 0`. After this change, next time you run `yum update`, you should not get any priority protections.

Comment: I signed in just to upvote this. My openssh was not getting updated to the latest version because the priority setting was enabled. This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the 'set enabled = ' worked for me. It would be nice to tease more information from yum - such as the names of the affected packages and the repositories they come from. (Is this a separate question?)

Comment: You can also disable the plugin from `yum`'s command line with this line:
`--disableplugin=priorities`

Comment: DO NOT RUN `yum erase yum-plugin-priorities`. You will lose sudo access and be unable to SSH into your server.

Comment: Is it a best practice to disable priorities then?

Answer (score 53):

In case you want to know which packages are excluded due to priority protections you can use

```
yum list updates --debuglevel 3
```

Comment: What does -d3 do exactly?

Comment: `-d3` increases the debuglevel so that `yum list updates` shows excluded packages.

Comment: `-d [debug level], --debuglevel=[debug level]` - I updated the answer to use the long option to be self-documenting