# Installing ODBC driver 13 for MSSQL Server in Amazon Linux on EC2 instance

Tags: linux, php, amazon-ec2, sql-server

**Problem:**

Need to access and execute the MSSQL Stored Procedure from PHP code.

**Version details:**

Local development machine - **Windows 10 with XAMPP with PHP 7**

Production system - **Amazon AWS AMI Linux with PHP 5.3.2**

**What I require:**

Want to use odbc connection to access the MSSQL on my LOCAL as well as LIVE server.

**What I tried for LIVE server:**

Wanted to make sure that the LIVE server is compatible to packages and am able to install the required packages correctly.

Hence, started with the following steps:

1) Looked in the link below where I found that we need to use ODBC for faster data access:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105561

2) Tried to install following ODBC driver on Amazon Linux as mentioned below:

***(Assuming that RHEL 6 installer would work on Amazon Linux too. Please let me know in case am incorrect)***

- Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server - Windows + Linux

> sudo su curl packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo >
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
>
> exit
>
> sudo yum remove unixODBC #to avoid conflicts
>
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql-13.0.1.0-1 mssql-tools

But installer fails showing below error:

```
Error: msodbcsql conflicts with unixODBC-utf16-2.3.1-1.x86_64
Error: Package: msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
           Requires: unixODBC >= 2.3.1
           Available: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.7.amzn1.i686 (amzn-main)
               unixODBC = 2.2.14-14.7.amzn1
```

3) Hence, tried to install the unixODBC using http://www.unixodbc.org/

```
- Downloaded the package via curl
- gunzip unixODBC*.tar.gz
- tar xvf unixODBC*.tar
```

Then, used the following commands to install the same:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

4) Restarted httpd service and again tried step 2 but installer failed with same error mentioned in point 2.

**What I tried for LOCAL machine:**

1. Downloaded the .msi file for Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server - Windows + Linux
2. Installed the same on my machine and restarted xampp apache.
   But am still getting `Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver`

**UPDATE**: Resolved the issue in local system by adding the extension dll in php.ini and restarted the server.

**Could anyone please let me know what have I missed in LIVE configuration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach to solution**

As the direct link for installation was not working, had downloaded rpm files for offline installation using below lines:

`sudo mkdir /tmp/RedHat6Packages`

`sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/6/prod/msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/RedHat6Packages/msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

`sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/6/prod/mssql-tools-14.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/RedHat6Packages/mssql-tools-14.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

Tried to install offline with following commands:
`cd /tmp/RedHat6Packages/`
`sudo yum localinstall msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
`sudo yum localinstall mssql-tools-14.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

But still was getting the same error:
`error: Failed dependencies:
        libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) is needed by msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64
        unixODBC >= 2.3.1 is needed by msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64`

Found command to check the packages:
`sudo yum provides /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2`

This showed following warning:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
unixODBC-2.2.14-14.7.amzn1.x86_64 : A complete ODBC driver manager for Linux
Repo        : amzn-main
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2    

unixODBC-utf16-2.3.1-1.x86_64 : ODBC driver manager with UTF16 character conversion enabled by default
Repo        : packages-microsoft-com-prod
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2
```

**JUMP directly to solution**

Checked the below mentioned link:

[What does that mean: packages excluded due to repository priority protections](https://serverfault.com/questions/312472/what-does-that-mean-packages-excluded-due-to-repository-priority-protections)

Disabled priorities by editing `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf` and set `enabled = 0`

Was able to install the driver using the same commands mentioned:
`cd /tmp/RedHat6Packages/`
`sudo yum localinstall msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
`sudo yum localinstall mssql-tools-14.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

Still unable to figure out where are extension files but have created other question ([Next steps after installation of MSSQL ODBC 13.1 on Amazon EC2 Linux](https://serverfault.com/q/840067/405368)) as purpose of this question is solved.

As a newbie to linux (esp. who have migrated from windows), it was really difficult to find the above solution. Hope it helps someone!!

Comment: Setting enabled = 0 had no effect for me, but I installed the local RPM using "sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps mssql-tools-14.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm" instead of "sudo yum localinstall"

Answer (score 1):

Here are the commands which should work for Amazon Linux AMI:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo1
sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel
sudo yum info unixODBC*
sudo yum install mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' | tee -a ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Source: [Install sqlcmd and bcp the SQL Server command-line tools on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools).

---

Otherwise, try to install older version which is not conflicting as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44141081/55075), e.g.

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql-13.0.1.0-1 mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1
```